# Visual Studio 2015 crashes on rename

Tags: crash, refactoring, visual-studio-2015

For some projects VS 2015 crashes when I try to **rename** a symbol (F2). If I create a new project it works fine, but my main task is a older project where my colleagues uses VS 2013 and there it keeps crashing.

I have found a possible solution which states that I should uncheck "Use undo transactions". The problem is that I can't find this setting in Visual Studio. Where is it? Or am I on the wrong track?

Answer (score 0):

Did you already check this [CodeMaid issue](https://github.com/codecadwallader/codemaid/issues/142)?

That settings you mentioned seems related to CodeMaid extension, not to Visual Studio on its own. I don't have that extension, but the options seem either to avoid *Undo transactions* altogether, or keep them enabled but *Skip during automatic cleanup on save*.

Comment: I have the above problem is VS2015 but I have not installed that extension. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: sorry, no. I haven't even experienced those crashes myself. Maybe @junior can shed a light if s/he solved the issue